# Chrome extension postMessage with user action

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I created [long-lived connection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#connect) between popup and content pages. It works successfully. But I want to **send message to content when user click the button**.

**contentscript.js**

```
console.log("content script loaded!");
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "content-script"});
port.onMessage.addListener(function(message){
    if(message.key=="color"){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';
    }
    else if(message.key=="color2"){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor='blue';
    }
});
```

**popup.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('btnStart');
    checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function() {  
      GetImages("");
    }, false);
  }, false);

 function GetImages(pageURL){
      if(activePort!=null){
        activePort.postMessage({key:"color2"});
      }
}

var activePort=null;
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
    console.assert(port.name == "content-script");
    activePort=port;
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {    
        if(message.key=="download"){
            port.postMessage({key:"download", text: "OK"});
        }
        else if(message.key="load"){
            port.postMessage({key:"color"});
            console.log(message.text);
        }
    })
});
```

In the GetImages() function I try to

```
port.postMessage({key:"color2"});
```

naturally it can't find the "port". So I create the activePort variable and try to post message with it. But It didn't work properly.

Comment: The popup runs each time it's shown and stops when hidden so this approach won't work. You'll have to reverse the direction: open the connection in the popup and listen in the content script. Note however, port-based messaging is usually a totally unnecessary overkill, the [simple messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) is perfectly fine.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you for your response. I reverse the direction and open connection in the popup I get error "Attempting to use a disconnected port object" when I try port.postMessage() in GetImages() function

Comment: Since I can't see what you're doing now I can't help.

Comment: To connect to the content script you need chrome.tabs.connect with a tab id, not chrome.runtime.connect. Also, did you copypaste correctly? I see the same onMessage used in both scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the codes below and it works correctly. Now I opened the port in popup.js and I can send message with button click.

**newpopup.js**

```
function GetImages(pageURL){
   port.postMessage({text:"ok"});
}
var port;
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    port = chrome.tabs.connect(tabs[0].id,{name: "knockknock"});
});
```

**newcontentscript.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    console.assert(port.name == "knockknock");
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
      console.log(msg);
    });
  });
```